# Reading from one csv vs reading from folder and then from csv

Tags: java, database, csv

I've a question about organizing a small program's database. I'm going to code a little program which only has to be able to add/edit/delete customers and add notes / images to them if needed. They can have as much notes or images as need. That means 0, 1 or even 1000.

My question is : I don't want to use a database I need to install, nor a OS depending one.

Therefore, I want to know if it's better to have one folder per customer which contains a csv with the customer's information and all the notes in form of a .txt file + images if there are any.

OR

Have one csv file with all customers and have all notes / images in one file and have the names of the files in the customer csv row to reference them.

Thank you for reading. If there already is such a software I would highly like them suggested to me since I couldn't find any.

Comment: What is your app architecture? A multi-tenant web app? Using plain Servlets or JSP? Using [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com)? Or is this a desktop app built with Swing, JavaFX, or SWT?

Comment: [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) is a pure java database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *H2 Database Engine*

> I don't want to use a database I need to install, nor a OS depending one.

The [*H2 Database Engine*](https://h2database.com/html/main.html) can be embedded within your app, so no need to install separately. And H2 is pure Java, so independent of platform.

H2 is a full-featured SQL-based JDBC-compliant relational database system. The product is actively developed and quite popular.

Comment: I've heard and read it's used a lot in developement and rarely in production is it also true for small apps?

Answer (score 1):

## SQLite3

> I don't want to install, or any OS dependency

You could use SQLite3 this Database is not dependent on os and you don't have to install it in a complicated way. H2 is a good system to so you can choose.

Comment: I've heard and read it's used a lot in developement and rarely in production is it also true for small apps?

Comment: Well I didn't heard of that it is rather an architecture thing. If you don't want to work with a big overhead than you can use SQLite3. This especially important when working on small projects because you definitely don't want overhead there.